# MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion with automatic migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm new to EF6 and I have an application that uses automatic migrations. Hence, when I change something in the database it's enough to run `Update-Database` to automatically apply the migrations needed.

Now I want to let the application to update the db when the model changes (Code-First).

I'm following this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx), here the line I need:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, Configuration>());
```

but the description says:

> When we create an instance of this initializer we need to specify the context type (BlogContext) and the migrations configuration (Configuration) - the migrations configuration is the class that got added to our Migrations folder when we enabled Migrations.

Because I'm using automatic migrations I have not a Migration folder and I don't understand what Configuration class I have to provide to the function.

Comment: Search your project for the text `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled`, you should find some configuration file this way. Your project needs to know that automatic migrations are enabled, so it needs some Configuration class.

Comment: Good hint. Found, I was searching in the wrong place.

Comment: Voting to close because *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced"* - I think that's close enough as a description for not finding an existing class :)